# JavaScript method of object not working

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to create a simple object with a method that changes the value of one of the keys. I want to initialize the isFoodWarm key to false, output the value, change it to true, then output it again. My expected output is false and then true, as the method should change it to true, but I am getting an error. I tried removing the parentheses from myBreakfast.heat();, which got rid of the error, but then it didn't successfully change the value. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code.

```
function Breakfast(food, drink, isFoodWarm) {
    this.food = food,
    this.drink = drink,
    this.isFoodWarm = isFoodWarm,
    heat = function() {
        if (isFoodWarm === false){
            isFoodWarm = true;
            console.log("your food is now warm");
        }
    }

}

var myBreakfast = new Breakfast("english muffin", "OJ", "false");

console.log(myBreakfast.isFoodWarm);
myBreakfast.heat();
console.log(myBreakfast.isFoodWarm);
```

I get the following console output:
false
Uncaught TypeError: myBreakfast.heat is not a function

Comment: `heat` is not a method of your instance. Also, you probably want to manipulate the properties (`this.isFoodWarm`) not the variables.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object/13418980#13418980

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach heat method to constructor `BreakFast` too. And also `isFoodWarm` is a property so it must be accessed using `this.isFoodWarm` inside the `heat` method.

```
this.heat=function() {
    if (this.isFoodWarm === false){
        this.isFoodWarm = true;
        console.log("your food is now warm");
    }
}
```

Explanation : Without `this` operator heat method gets attached to global object, so when you call `myBreakfast.heat` it gives an `Uncaught TypeError` because it is defined under `window.heat`.

**Note** : when you need to pass a boolean then don't wrap it inside quotes as it will change your boolean to string which will behave like true.

so change your constructor call to

```
new Breakfast("english muffin", "OJ", false);  \\remove double quotes around false
```

**Demo**

```js
function Breakfast(food, drink, isFoodWarm) {
    this.food = food,
    this.drink = drink,
    this.isFoodWarm = isFoodWarm,
    this.heat = function() {
        if (this.isFoodWarm === false){
            this.isFoodWarm = true;
            console.log("your food is now warm");
        }
    }

}

var myBreakfast = new Breakfast("english muffin", "OJ", false);

console.log(myBreakfast.isFoodWarm);
myBreakfast.heat();
console.log(myBreakfast.isFoodWarm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `heat` function is not bound to object of instance of `Breakfast` class. You can easily fix it by adding `heat` as property to `this` inside `Breakfast` class constructor:

```
function Breakfast(food, drink, isFoodWarm) {
    this.food = food,
    this.drink = drink,
    this.isFoodWarm = isFoodWarm,
    this.heat = function() {
        if (this.isFoodWarm === false){
            this.isFoodWarm = true;
            console.log("your food is now warm");
        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**: Also change `isFoodWarm` in function `heat` to `this.isFoodWarm`.

Comment: Still `console.log(myBreakfast.isFoodWarm);` wouldn't yield the expected result

Comment: This got rid of the error, but it still isn't changing the value to true.

Comment: Answer updated. didn't noticed that you use local variable instead of property in function `heat`.